# Can anyone identify this like plugin (not facebook like)?

Tags: plugins

Almost all divs say **wpl** but can't find which plugin is.
For example, `#wpl-likebox`.

Here is a page that is using it:

http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/jquery-updates-in-wordpress-3-2/

Comment: did you email the site owner to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [custom Plugin](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/like-a-post/) for WordPress.com.

Comment: Thanks! You made my made! EDIT: Wait a minute, can it be downloaded as a plugin?

Comment: I don't think that one is available publicly. Take a look at JetPack, and see if it's included there. If it's not, then it likely hasn't (yet, at least) been released.

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin out...
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/screenshots/

"Plugin allows you to set up advanced rating and review system for post types and comments in your blog using single, multi and thumbs ratings."

I've used it for other sites in the 5 star rating mode but I haven't try the single star/like mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Disqus](http://disqus.com) for your comment system and it has a built in like button similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this plugin: [Gravatar Like](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravatar-like/).

I found it on several blogs so it can't be a custom one

Comment: Hi and welcome! Case you haven't noticed, this is an old Question and was already answered. I checked the code of the plugin you're linking and `wpl` is not there :/ Nice try, though :)